# Bash tab completion adds extra space after the first completion

Tags: bash, tab-completion

Bash tab completion adds extra space after the first completion which stops further completion if the compeletion target is a file in multi-level folders.

For example, I have a file in the path ~/Documents/foo/bar.txt, and I want to list it.
I face the following problem, when input

```
a@b:~$ls Docu <TAB>
```

I get

```
a@b:~$ls Documents |(<-this is the cursor, so there is an extra space afer Documents)
```

So I cannot further tab complete. I have to backspace to delete the extra space.

Normally I want to get:

```
a@b:~$ls Docu <TAB>
a@b:~$ls Documents/ <TAB>
a@b:~$ls Documents/foo/ <TAB>
a@b:~$ls Documents/foo/bar.txt
```

Comment: This is so annoyinggggggggg. It seems there's a bug filed on Ubuntu https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acroread/+bug/769866

Answer (score 22):

Just for the record: There is also a bug in the adobereader-enu (acroread) package that breaks bash completion. In this case you can just delete the symlink:

```
rm /etc/bash_completion.d/acroread.sh
```

See also: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acroread/+bug/769866

Comment: removed.. and fixed :)

Comment: Same here, nice catch!

Comment: We have to install acroread for application compatibility on RHEL8. It wasn't causing any issue up to and including RHEL7, so discovering this 7 years later is a prime example of why moderators need to get off their "thread resurrection" high horse. There are _extremely good_ reasons why a question from "9 years and 1 month ago" might be not just relevant today, but new even.

Answer (score 6):

I have had this same problem with my bash completion in both Ubuntu 11.10 and 12.04.  I found that I was able to get many commands to start working correctly by editing /etc/bash_completion.  Specifically, I commented out the following section:

```
####
# makeinfo and texi2dvi are defined elsewhere.
#
#for i in a2ps awk bash bc bison cat colordiff cp csplit \
#    curl cut date df diff dir du enscript env expand fmt fold gperf gprof \
#    grep grub head indent irb ld ldd less ln ls m4 md5sum mkdir mkfifo mknod \
#    mv netstat nl nm objcopy objdump od paste patch pr ptx readelf rm rmdir \
#    sed seq sha{,1,224,256,384,512}sum shar sort split strip tac tail tee \
#    texindex touch tr uname unexpand uniq units vdir wc wget who; do
#    have $i && complete -F _longopt -o default $i
#done
```

Now ls works well again.  I have not figured out yet why mv is still mis-behaving.

Comment: Thank you! I was going insane. This started happening to me after a fresh install of 12.04 (I'd never had the problem in earlier versions of Ubuntu. My old system had been dist-upgraded to 11.10 though).

Comment: Thank you, this has been bugging me for MONTHS! I even filed a bug report, but nobody seemed to follow up on it. This worked just now, including for `mv`. Hoping I don't see any weird side effects, but I'm hopeful.

Answer (score 4):

This has been answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41707/bash-auto-completion-with-added-spaces-why-and-how-to-fix) at askubuntu. It is related to the bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/acroread/+bug/769866)

Relevant answer from the above thread:

> edit /etc/bash_completion line 1587, change default to filenames (make a backup first).

Answer (score 0):

i also got around the problem by changing
_filedir with _filedir_pdf
in /etc/bash_completion.d/acroread.sh
(Ubuntu 12.04)

acroread bash completion changes the _filedir function thereby altering the behaviour of a lot of other  alsobash completion functions